# Making the frame of a button triangle instead of rectangle in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, core-animation, uibezierpath

I have a button which has a triangle shaped image in it. Which looks like below.

[image]

This button also has a triangle clickable area. In order to do that I've created a UIButton class as below.

Button's clickable area is triangle but the frame of the button is still rectangle. How can I make the frame of the button a triangle? If there is a such way, I won't be using bezierpath to draw a clickable area because the frame will already be a triangle.

Thanks.

```
class triangleShapeButton: UIButton {
private let triangle = UIBezierPath()

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        triangle.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        triangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width/2, y: 0))
        triangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y:rect.height))
        triangle.close()
    }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        // This is for allow touches only in shape area.
        if triangle.contains(touches.first?.location(in: self) ?? .zero) {
            super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
         
        }
    }
```

EDIT: What I want to create is a circular shaped button set as below. And while doing that, the rectangular frames of some of the triangle buttons overlaps the next triangle button. This causes to block the clickable area of some of the triangle buttons. I've tried to change the layer hierarchy but at least 1 of the buttons still overlaps the other one. How can I solve that issue if I can not change the frame?

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: There is a method `contains(CGPoint)` in UIBezierPath. You can try that once. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624345-contains

Comment: The `frame` property of a UIView is always a `CGRect` and thus rectangular. As such, it's not possible to set the frame of a UIButton to be a triangle. But that should never be necessary in the first place. As you already discovered, you can just draw a custom triangle within the rectangle frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This means a lot. 
@JoRa What I've tried to explain was too long for comments so I've edited my question lol. Can you check it out? Thanks

Comment: @ChanOnly123 is there a method that makes exactly the opposite of contains(CGPoint)? something like "exclude" :D I couldn't find such thing. Thanks

Comment: You just have to munge hit testing on the superview.

Comment: @matt what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean simply implement `hitTest` so that each button is touchable exactly in its triangle regardless of layering order.

Comment: @matt After your comment I've done some research. hitTest might be the solution. But hitTest needs a CGPoint to exclude from the touchable area. while what I need is an **area** to be excluded. How can I define the area that I want to exclude (as CGPoint)? 

++I draw that area with BezierPath, and tried to exclude it from the touchable area. then tried something like: if point != newBezierPath return nil. 

But nothing has changed there. What should I do next? My questions might be pretty ignorant. Excuse me for that :)

Comment: Obviously a point is not a path. But finding out whether a point is inside (contained by) a path is trivial, and that is exactly what you want to know here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest:

Draw your shapes using CAShapeLayers. If you ultimately want to fill those shapes with images, look at setting up layers where the contents of the layer is a CGImage. Add another CAShapeLayer to draw the border of the shape. Then apply a CAShapeLayer as a mask to crop the image to your triangle/circle wedge shape.

Now, for figuring out what the user tapped:
Build an array of your shape paths, and their frame rectangles. When you get a tap in your view, first loop through the array of rectangles and find all the rectangles that contain the tap point. (There may be more than one.)

Then loop through the smaller array where the tap was contained in the rectangle, and use `UIBezierPath.contains(point:)` or `CGPath.contains(_:using:transform:)` to figure out which of your shapes actually contains the tap point.

By first filtering your array to only those shapes who's frames contain the tap point, you use a very fast test to reduce the number of shapes you have to check using the much slower path contains() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some code in your existing code and you can try it. It might help you.
I recommend you to ask for rectangular shape image.

```
   class TriangleShapeButton: UIButton {
        
       let triangle = UIBezierPath()
       let triangleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            super.draw(rect)
            triangle.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
            triangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width/2, y: 0))
            triangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y:rect.height))
            
            triangleLayer.path = triangle.cgPath
            triangleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            self.layer.addSublayer(triangleLayer)
            triangle.close()
        }
        
        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            // This is for allow touches only in shape area.
            if triangle.contains(touches.first?.location(in: self) ?? .zero) {
                super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
                
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What your code does is creating a triangle CAShapeLayer. I already have a triangle shaped button. What I need is changing the frame or cropping some part of the frame. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach of changing the shape of a UIView is not possible. Every UIView is a rectangle at the low-level, so adjacent triangles as in your case will necessarily overlap.

But there is a different approach:

You can create a single class for the entire circular view. Inside this class, you modify the `drawRect` function in such a way, that the individual triangles (or circle segments) are drawn adjacent to each other.

Inside this class you can then override the `touchesBegan` method. There you can check for the touch position using `touches.first?.location(in: self)`. This will give you a `CGPoint`. Then you can manually check in which triangle the touch occurred and perform actions accordingly.

Comment: I've been thinking about your approach. In that case I have to draw the triangles and customize their appearance by myself. Here, in my example I did draw those triangles in AdobePhotoshop and saved them as png to be able to use inside of a UIbutton. If I did draw the triangles by myself, will be able to add some png images to those triangles? Hopefully I get your approach right. Thanks.

Comment: That could be possible, but I would have to do some research for that on my own. But there certainly is a way to draw png images inside drawRect().
But the shapes don't seem be that complicated. There are built-in `UIBezierPath` methods to draw arc segments, you can set a fill color or add a gradient layer. So drawing the shapes by yourself might be an easier way